# Returning a string pointer

Tags: c, linux, posix

I started learning C, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here is a simple code of a function that returns the pid+".data".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char * getfilename(){
    char name[60];
    sprintf(name,"%i.data",getpid());
    return name;
}

void main(){
    char* name = getfilename();
    printf("%s",name);
}
```

outputs: `��#�a`.

So I guess that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You should really compile with `gcc -Wall -g` to get all warnings and debugging info. GCC would have warned you. And then you may want to use `gdb` to debug the issue, once you have improved your code till no warnings are given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char * getfilename(){
    char name[60];
    sprintf(name,"%i.data",getpid());
    return name;
}
```

You cannot access `name` object after `getfilename` has returned. The lifetime of the automatic object `name` ends at the `getfilename` last `}`. Accessing it after the function returns is undefined behavior.

As a temporary fix you can specify `name` as `static` and it will work. But what you should do is to have the `getfilename` function accepts a pointer argument where the filename will be written.

**EDIT:**

Why I don't suggest to use `strdup`?

- `strdup` is not a Standard C function. `strdup` lives in the POSIX world. For portability reasons whenever I can, I prefer to use Standard C functions.
- `strdup` performs a hidden `malloc` call and you have not to forget to perform a `free`. This is contrary to all functions of the Standard C library which never call `malloc` (or actually that never *appear* to call `malloc`). `strdup` is a bad API design.
- `strdup` is performing a copy of a string. Why do you need to perform an extra copy? Just write the string in a place you can retrieve it.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup), i.e. change:

```
return name;
```

to:

```
return strdup(name);
```

This makes a copy of your temporary (local) string using dynamic memory allocation (i.e. [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)).

You must of course make sure that you subsequently [free](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) this string when you're done with it.

You'll need:

```
#include <string.h> // strdup()
#include <stdlib.h> // free()
```

Comment: I'll +1 if you include the relevant header file.

Answer (score 1):

```
char name[60]
```

lives on the stack, but only as long as being inside `getfilename()` afterwards its freed, so any references (as also returned by `getfilename()`) to it become invalid.

Answer (score 1):

`char name[60]` is a local variable which is allocated when the function is called and deallocated when it returns. When you try to return it, you're really returning it's address (after all arrays are mostly syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic). Now, your caller has a pointer to a block of memory that has been free, and thus will likely contain garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return the array `name` from your function `getfilename`, because it is a (regular) local variable and those get cleaned up when the function returnes.
So, when you get back in `main` and try to print the returned value, the pointer `name` there refers to a block of memory that has been reused for other purposes.

There are several solutions for this problem:

1. Make `name` in `getfilename` `static`. This will ensure that it outlives the call to `getfilename` and can safely be returned, but has the drawback that all calls to `getfilename` use the same buffer.
2. Allocate the array dynamically with `malloc` (and don't forget to clean it up with `free` when you are done with it)
3. Pass the buffer to store the value in as a parameter.

Comment: One of the best answers. One question, what would be the problem with using the same buffer on the calls of getfilename?

Comment: In this particular case there are no problems. But imagine this code `char* one = getfilename(); char*two=getfilename();` where `getfilename` can fill the buffer with different contents on each call.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers you cannot return a pointer which points somewhere in the stack of a function.

You can simply pass the allocated array to `getfilename()` function. You can rewrite the program as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void getfilename(char * name)
{

    sprintf(name,"%i.data",getpid());
}

int main(void)
{
    char name[60];
    getfilename(name);
    printf("%s\n",name);
    return 0;
}
```

This should work fine.